# SharePoint 2013 Description does not show for calculated fields

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, calculated-column

I have added descriptions to calculated fields in a SharePoint 2013 list, but am unable to make them display in the form like other column descriptions. How can I add these to be visible to my users?

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint "Description" column is the type of **Multiline of Text** - by the designed of SharePoint, we cannot create a calculated column out of **Multiline of Text** type column. Because of this limitation, though in my list I have added the "Description" column it does not show while creating the calculated column.

[image: Multiline Text column does not show in the calculated column creation]

**Solution**:

Create a sample workflow using that update your desired column with the description column value.

You may look into the below trick workaround to create the calculated column out of multiline text column:

[How to trick a Calculated column into referring to a Multiple Lines of Text column](https://wowsomuch.com/sharepoint/calculated-column-refer-to-multiple-lines-of-text-column/)

Answer (score 0):

I think following points should answer your question:

1. If you are talking about the **Description** you give to the fields in their settings. Which will be shown on the list forms as instructions to users then:

   As calculated columns are not shown on the list new/edit forms there is no OOTB way you can show the description of the calculated columns on list form.
2. If you are are trying to use SharePoint OOTB **Description** column in calculated column formula then it is not possible to use it in formula as this is the multiple lines of text column (and multiple lines of text columns are not supported in calculated column formulas).

Answer (score 0):

From your description, you want to show Description for Calculated fields.

By default, Calculated fields are not showed in NewForm or EditForm, so, users also could not see its description. It is normal behavior.

For your request, as a workaround, you can create another column using another column type (eg. Single Line of text) instead of Calculated type, then create a SharePoint Designer workflow to do the calculation and set calculated value to the new column.